# Getting a null object reference error in Android after initializing object

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is what my code is doing:

MainActivity is passing an object "device" using intents to ItemListActivity:

```
// When button is clicked to go to ItemListActivity
car = new Car();
device = new Device(car);
intent.putExtra("device", device);
```

The device object has a Car object as a field, and both implement serializable.

Now Car is also a fragment class, and so in ItemListActivity, I'd like to have an option to open the car fragment in the device object that was passed through intent. (This is a master/detail flow activity)

ItemListActivity:

```
// in onCreate //
Intent intent = getIntent();
Device device = (Device) intent.getSerializableExtra("device");

View recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.item_list);
assert recyclerView != null;
setupRecyclerView((RecyclerView) recyclerView);
//////////////////

private void setupRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(this, ItemsContent.ITEMS, mTwoPane, device));
}

public static class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ...
    private Device mDevice;

    // Here's the problem:
    Car car = mDevice.getCar(); // getCar just returns the private Car field in Device

    private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ItemsContent.ItemsPage item = (ItemsContent.ItemsPage) view.getTag();
            if (mTwoPane) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, item.id);

                Fragment fragment;
                fragment = car;
                mParentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
                ...
            }
        }
    ...
    SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(ItemListActivity parent,
                                  List<ItemsContent.ItemsPage> items,
                                  boolean twoPane, Device device) {
        mValues = items;
        mParentActivity = parent;
        mTwoPane = twoPane;
        mDevice = device;
    }
}
```

(A lot of the code is just filler master/detail flow activity stuff but let me know if you want to see that too)

The error I'm getting when I try opening up ItemListActivity from main is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'Device.getCar()' on a null object reference
```

But I don't really understand why this is happening because even I just set car = null, my app runs until I enter the ItemListActivity and select the Car fragment. Then the app crashes, but I don't see how setting car = mDevice.getCar() doesn't allow my app to even make it to the ItemListActivity from main, and so I'm confused why I'm getting a null error when I try to open ItemListActivity. Thanks!

edit: Added constructor code

Comment: You declare mDevice and it is null `private Device mDevice;`. On the very next line of code you try to call a method on that null object `Car car = mDevice.getCar();` so you get a NPE..

Comment: Oh I forgot to post the constructor, but in setUpRecyclerView, the device is a parameter, and mDevice = device gets called

Comment: Does not matter since you wrote `mDevice.getCar();` outside of the constructor. If the code sample you gave does not represent the actual situation then you need to update the question.

Comment: Edited to add the constructor in that class. So when I call setUpRecyclerView, will the constructor not set mDevice = device first, and then continue the code? How should I assign mDevice before calling getCar() then? @takendarkk

Comment: "_will the constructor not set mDevice = device first_" No, that happens after `mDevice.getCar();` since that has been written at the class level rather than being inside a method. Just take the method call that throws the NPE and put it _into_ your constructor at the end - there is no need for it to be at the class level.

Comment: Hmm, so now I'm getting a null error on the line mParentActivity....commit();.
What I did was change my class level initialization to Car car;, and added the line car = device.getCar() at the end of the constructor.  But the fragment is still null even after fragment = car, do you have any idea why? @takendarkk